# IBoutlet not working on xCode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uibutton, iboutlet

I have a problem with IBOutlet and their connecting - do not want to connect with the respective controllers. I do not know how to describe it.

I have the latest version of Xcode.

Screen:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Ddwwpex.png]

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made sure to specify the view controller's custom class in the identity inspector? It must be the same as your subclass (in your case, "ViewController")

[image]